# How do I approach this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation

My guess is that this is a recursively defined sequence but I cannot figure out how to formulate it. Obviously, the sum is of an odd number of consecutive integers, so the sum will be of 2n+1 integers, but I cannot tie it back into the final equation.

Riddle:
let E be a sequence of equations:
\begin{align*}
E_1 & : \; 2+3+4 = 1 + 8 \cr
E_2 & : \; 5+6+7+8+9 = 8+27 \cr
E_3 & : \; 10+11+12+13+14+15+16 = 27+64
\end{align*}
Find $E_4,E_5$ and $E_6$, then find an equation for $E_n$. Finally, prove your equation for $E_n$.

Also, any help for thinking through recursive problems would be great!

Comment: First $1^3+2^3$, then $2^3+3^3$, then $3^3+4^3$. I suppose you see the pattern.

Comment: holy hell I feel dense right now, thanks

Comment: So did you see $E_4$ already?

Comment: yup! E_n = n^3 + (n+1)^3

Comment: Ahhh I see! En is the sum of $(2n+1)$ consecutive integers, for $n>=1$, so the proof would be to show $E_n = (n^3 + (n+1)^3)$ for all-natural number n?

Comment: Try to use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to guess the formula $E_n$ as
$$
E_n:\quad (n^2+1)+(n^2+2)+\cdots +(n+1)^2=n^3+(n+1)^3
$$
from the equations for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$. Once you have guessed the formula, you can easily prove it by induction.

Comment: How did you find $(n^2+1)+(n^2+2)+...+(n+1)^2$ ?

Comment: Exactly as the exercise says. Start with $E_1: 2+3+4$. Then $E_2:5+6+7+8+9$, and then... well? How starts it with $E_4$? What was the hint you got? "Find $E_4$ and $E_6$..." By the way, what happened to $E_5$? Did they forget it? So find $E_4,E_5,E_6$, and then you know how it goes.

Comment: Hrmrmm that's good, the starting integer is always $(n^2+1)$ and the ending integer $(n+1)^2$ I hadn't noticed that, I was trying to work with $2n+1$, which when you take the summation is $(n^2+1)$

Comment: Thank you though I should be able to prove it from here! Do you know where I can find good problems like this? I'd like to diversify away from just my text book.

Comment: I'm not sure i've proved this correctly, I have backed out $k^3+(k+1)^3$ from $(k+1)^3+((k+1)+1)^3$ as $k^3+(k+1)^3 + (6k^2+12k+8)$ does this suffice?

Comment: Since you've never accepted any answer ... it is your turn! You can do it!

Comment: hrmrrmm, well the issue is showing LHS = RHS, with k+1 the LHS gets's quite messy, if i can find the $(k+1)^2$ in the LHS and match it with the $k^3+(k+1)^3$ on the RHS I will have shown the progression no?

Comment: hrmrrmm, well the issue is showing LHS = RHS, with k+1 the LHS gets's quite messy, if i can find the $(k+1)^2$ in the LHS and match it with the $k^3+(k+1)^3$ on the RHS I will have shown the progression no?

Comment: What do you mean by "never accepted any answer"? i'm trying to understand it! hahaha

Comment: Each answer to your questions can be accepted by you (click on it). You have posted $7$ questions, and never accepted any answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to accept an answer.

Comment: Damn, sorry about that

Comment: No problem. Induction works by assuming the formula $E_k$ and deriving $E_{k+1}$. So you have to show $(k+1)^2+1+\cdots=(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3$ using $E_k$.

Comment: I got it thanks!